# After recording, I cannot run this code

Tags: vba, excel

I write 1 file VBA Macro Excel.
First, I record. The command is OK.
But when I run this code I get an error:

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error

Here is my command:

```
SUMIFS(CSDL4G!F:F,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)*SUMIFS(CSDL4G!H:H,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)*(SUMIFS(CSDL4G!J:J,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)+SUMIFS(CSDL4G!L:L,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47))/SUMIFS(CSDL4G!E:E,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)/SUMIFS(CSDL4G!G:G,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)/(SUMIFS(CSDL4G!I:I,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47)+SUMIFS(CSDL4G!K:K,CSDL4G!D:D,'KPI Huyen'!B47))*100
```

Here is my code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[-1],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])*SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[1],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])*(SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[3],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])+SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[5],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5]))/SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[-2],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])/SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C,CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])/(SUMIFS(CSDL4G!C[2],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5])+S" & _
    "DL4G!C[4],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5]))*100"
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your last part of the statement is corrupted.  You have:

```
... +S" & _
    "DL4G!C[4],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5]))*100"
```

but it should have been

```
... +SUMIFS(CS" & _
    "DL4G!C[4],CSDL4G!C[-3],'KPI Huyen'!RC[-5]))*100"
```